# Grunt | Throw Compilation Error to Powershell

Tags: powershell, gruntjs

I am trying to call Grunt command from my powershell script. But in case of any complilation failure Grunt is printing the error code to the console but not returning anything to powershell command line and even not going to catch block.

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: can you provide code examples?

Answer (score 1):

Noah's answer (using **$ErrorActionPreference**) can work.   Alternatively you can use the automatic variables **$?** and/or **$LastExitCode** immediately after executing the external command to take a specific action if it failed.   This doesn't require a try-catch block   For example:

```
Grunt.exe -whatever
if (!$?) { throw "Grunt command returned $LastExitCode" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a screenshot of what is happening or more details it is hard to say what is going on here. However, the basics of PS are that you need to make sure the error is considered terminating for the catch block to trigger. Since this does not sound like a native PS cmdlet you can force it to be a terminating error like below:

```
Try {
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
Grunt.exe whatever
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
}
Catch {stuff}
```