# Get Grunt Exit Code In PowerShell

Tags: node.js, powershell, gruntjs

Basically the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443739/grunt-throw-compilation-error-to-powershell).  I am setting up a PowerShell script for TFS to run during the build.  When I execute the Grunt command through the command prompt, I get an error (as expected).  However, when running the command through PowerShell, no error is reported.

My Powershell:

```
C:\...\grunt --gruntfile $pathOfGruntFile + "\gruntfile.js" prod-build
Write-Output $?
```

This returns true every time.  I have also tried

```
C:\...\grunt --gruntfile $pathOfGruntFile + "\gruntfile.js" prod-build
Write-Output $LASTEXITCODE
```

But that returns a null every time.

I have also tried using Diagnostics.Process, as [documented here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/117):

```
$process = New-Object Diagnostics.Process
$process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\...\npm\grunt"
$process.StartInfo.Arguments = @('--gruntfile', "C:\...\gruntfile.js", 'prod-build')

$process.Start()
$process.Close()

Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
if ($process.ExitCode -ne 0) {throw $process.ExitCode}
```

When using this last method, it always throws "ScriptHalted", regardless of whether the Grunt process succeeds or fails.

If the Grunt tasks fail, I need to stop the build.  How can I capture the Grunt exit code in PowerShell, or at least know if the Grunt script failed?

Comment: check the $global:LastExitCode variable

Comment: @jisaak Same result at using `$LASTEXITCODE`

Comment: Don't suppose the downvoter would like to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what I wanted to do, but it works as expected.  I managed to get the third method from the question to work, with only minor modifications:

```
[string] $pathRemoveReadOnly = $Env:TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY + "\src\...\"
[string] $pathGruntCliBase = "C:\...\npm\"
$files = Get-ChildItem -File -Path $pathRemoveReadOnly -Recurse

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    Set-ItemProperty $file.FullName -Name IsReadOnly -Value $False
}

# Took and modified this script from https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/117
$global:finalMessage = $null
$gruntCmdFile = $pathGruntCliBase + "grunt.cmd"
$gruntFile = $pathRemoveReadOnly + "gruntfile.js"

$process = New-Object Diagnostics.Process
$process.StartInfo.FileName = $gruntCmdFile
$process.StartInfo.Arguments = @('--gruntfile', $gruntFile, 'prod-build', '--verbose', '--no-color')
$process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true

@{SourceIdentifier = 'GruntOutput'; EventName = 'OutputDataReceived'},
@{SourceIdentifier = 'GruntError'; EventName = 'ErrorDataReceived'} |
  %{
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $_.SourceIdentifier `
      -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $process @_
  }
-
$process.Start() | Out-Null
$process.BeginOutputReadLine()
$process.BeginErrorReadLine()

function Get-EventMessages([string[]]$names)
{
  $names |
    % { Get-Event -SourceIdentifier $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue } |
    % {
      if ($_.SourceEventArgs.Data)
      {
        #Uncomment this line if you want to see the output
        #Write-Host $_.SourceEventArgs.Data
        $global:finalMessage = $_.SourceEventArgs.Data
      }
      Remove-Event -EventIdentifier $_.EventIdentifier
    }
}

while (!$process.WaitForExit(100))
{
  Get-EventMessages -names 'GruntOutput', 'GruntError'
}

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
Get-EventMessages -names 'GruntOutput', 'GruntError'
$process.Close()

if ($global:finalMessage -ne 'Done, without errors.') { throw 'Build aborted! Grunt failed.'}
```

The `$process.ExitCode` that the original author was using always came back as null.  To counter that, I added the `$global:finalMessage` variable, and simply read the very last message from the output.  If it it says "Done, without errors." then I know it succeeded.  Anything else indicates a failure in the Grunt process.